# ROR + Error For nil:NilClass In Rake Task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null, rake-task

In my Rake Command I am calling XML to retrieve data. If person_id is valid, then it saved. But I am getting error.

```
if !@case.person_id.nil?
    @project.team_members << @person
 end
```

Error :: rake aborted! undefined method `team_members' for nil:NilClass

Please Suggest Some Thing !!!

Comment: Like the error message says your `@project` is nil.

Comment: As people are suggesting, the problem is not just in the code you show here. You need to show where `@project` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@project is a nil variable and this is why you cannot invoke team_members. Check how you define it. Moreover, you may want to follow the ruby way of doing things. 'If not' occasions are better to write like :

```
unless @case.person_id.nil?
  ...
```

Comment: That's a good point that you mentioned `unless`, but notice that there's still `nil?`. You might want to go a step further and switch back to `if` (Double negation is affirmative).

Comment: @sawa, i understand your point, unless nil is indeed a debate point in ruby. I personally like unless nil better than plain if (is more like english to me). But i understand that others like plain if better. I feel that the latter is more of a php or C++ style and (again personally) prefer to read unless nil. But certainly, your comment is good and people should indeed choose between the two depending on their coding style.